# How to return string value from an array, based on another variable?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following code and would like to return the string value for `aaa`, depending on what is in the `ADProps.physicalDeliveryOfficeName` supplied to the `GetOfficeLocation` function.

The switch seems to do what it should but it won't return the string value, perhaps I am referencing it incorrectly when outputting `$a["aaa"]`?

```
$global:newcastle = @{
"Value 1 newcastle" = @{
    "aaa" = "newcastle string";
    }
}

$global:london = @{
"Value 1 london" = @{
    "aaa" = "london string";
    }
}

$global:heathrow = @{
"Value 1 heathrow" = @{
    "aaa" = "heathrow string";
    }
}

$ADProps=@{
    'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'= "heathrow airport";
}

function GetOfficeLocation ($office) {
    switch ( $office )
    {
    "newcastle" {$location = "newcastle"; break}
    "london city" {$location = "london"; break}
    "heathrow airport" {$location = "heathrow"; break}
    }
    return $location
}

$a = GetOfficeLocation($ADProps.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)
$a["aaa"]
```

Result is that nothing gets output to the console.

Desired result in this example would be for this to be displayed: `heathrow string`

Effectively I am trying to determine which @global variable to choose and then access its members from then on.

*edit*

How do I return the value `heathrow string`, based on passing `heathrow airport` as a parameter into the `GetOfficeLocation` function? I would also like to be able to return `newcastle string` or `london string` by changing the input accordingly.

Comment: $a - will return 'heathrow', not sure what you are trying to achieve. i can understand what you are trying to do but have a feeling there is some serious overengineering happening here

Comment: @4c74356b41 This is a sample that I have simplified purely for posting here, in order to replicate the functionality on a basic level. The actual code contains various global arrays containing lists of Active Directory OU's. These are split by office location and further by department but there is only one element in each sub-array (the `aaa` bit). I'm importing a CSV with names, job titles, office location, department, etc, then trying to determine which OU to place a new user in. There is unfortunately too much code to post here but if I can figure out this bit, I can make it work.

Comment: whatever you are trying to do doesnt make sense after reading this question, can you edit it to make it understandable

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reach this using hashtable. Like so:

```
$HashTable = @{
    'newcastle' = 'newcastle';
    'london city' = 'london';
    'heathrow airport' = 'heathrow';
}

$ADProps=@{
    'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'= "heathrow airport";
}
```

Calling key `'heathrow airport'` will return its corresponding value `heathrow`

```
$HashTable[$ADProps.physicalDeliveryOfficeName]
heathrow
```

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
heathrow = @{
    aaa = "heathrow string"
}
$a = GetOfficeLocation($ADProps.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)
(Get-Variable -Name $a).value.aaa
```

but i dont know, code is completely not clear